# Version Control for Powerapps - Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, powerapps

We want to use Version control for PowerApps code. Which one we can use?
Is Bitbucket can be used with PowerApps?

Answer (score 1):

By using SolutionPackager tool you can extract the solution code and then you can commit it to your Repository
for more details, you can check this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/compress-extract-solution-file-solutionpackager)

Answer (score 0):

As of now there's no external version control available for powerapps.

You can either use help of inbuilt versioning of powerapps (it can restore changes of last 6 months but you should be providing meaningful comments while saving new version each time so you get a fair idea of version you are about to restore in near future),

or create a new copy of app by using **save as** option to store working copy upto a release date.

Answer (score 0):

PowerApps does have Git integration as one of it's experimental features to allow for external version control of solutions; However, you should be very careful when deciding whether to use it or not - it still has various flaws causing issues when building more complex solutions using the platform, but can be very useful for smaller scale apps.

See documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/git-version-control